# "In Partnership of/with the Embassy?"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, pronouns

Which way is correct?

> In Partnership of the Embassy of Spain...
>   or
>   In Partnership with the Embassy of Spain...

Answer (score 2):

To ***[partner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/partner)*** is usually followed by the preposition ***with***:

> - (v. int) To become partners or work or associate as partners: *partnered with a friend in a new venture.*
> - ( v.tr.)
>   To be or make a partner of: *She was partnered with her brother in the canoe race.* (The Free Dictionry)

- Its noun form ***partnership*** is generally followed by the same preposition as shown [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20partnership%20with%2C%20in%20partnership%20of%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20partnership%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20partnership%20of%3B%2Cc0).

The preposition ***of*** is used in sentences like:

- with the partnership of :

> - For the next several years he continued his career *with the partnership of* Rosen- Balsinger and Associates. ([The Good Neighbour](https://books.google.it/books?id=dXPklwSEocoC&pg=PA259&dq=%22with%20the%20partnership%20of%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIvtm-65WFyAIVx24UCh0SnQXl#v=onepage&q=%22with%20the%20partnership%20of%22&f=false))

So your sentence could be:

- in partnership with the Embassy of Spain

Or

- with the partnership of the Embassy of Spain.